# BigQuery SQL, append SQL query result to existing table

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery

I'm using Google Cloud Platform BigQuery SQL.

I have a table [myTable] and I'm writing the following SQL. I want to append the result of this SQL to myTable, but all I have managed so far is to replace myTable every time I run the SQL.

Can someone tell me what is the SQL sentence for **append the query results to an existing table**?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE myTable  -- myTable will be replace every time...
SELECT
  id,
  parameter1,
  parameter2
FROM 
  third_party_managerd_table
```

Comment: You can use append/overwrite setting in bigquery.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
INSERT `project.dataset.yourtable` (id, parameter1, parameter2) 
SELECT
  id,
  parameter1,
  parameter2
FROM 
  `project.dataset.third_party_managerd_table`
```

See more about BigQuery DML here - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax

Answer (score 1):

It can also be done by creating a new table with the new query and inserting it into "myTable"

```
CREATE OR REPLACE new_info
SELECT
  id,
  parameter1,
  parameter2
FROM 
  third_party_managerd_table;

INSERT INTO myTable
SELECT 
  n.*
FROM 
  new_info n;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running your queries with the `bq` command line tool, you can just use it with `--noreplace` argument to make sure you are appending data to your pre-existing table. Here is how:

```
bq --location=US query --noreplace --destination_table='project.dataset.yourtable' 'SELECT id, parameter1, parameter2 from `project.dataset.third_party_managerd_table`'
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: using `INSERT` does not involve any streaming - thus no any streaming cost incurred! please double check and correct your answer respectively. you can check https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#dml for details of dml charging

Comment: There is a cost involved with adding records to a table using DML `INSERT`. I have edited the answer to remove the word 'streaming'.

Comment: there is no such things like insert cost - you pay ONLY for number of bytes processed by the query!

Comment: I meant DML cost. There is a cost associated with every DML statement:  cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#dml

Comment: which is in case of INSERT is exactly the same as just cost of SELECT query involved in that INSERT query - so you should still correct your answer